# How many factors of $25 \times 36 \times 52$ are perfect squares?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

How many factors of $25 \times 36 \times 52$ are perfect squares?

How can we solve this with permutation and combinations?

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**:

$25\times 36\times 52= (5\times 6\times 2)^2\times 13$, so the greatest square factor is $(2^2\times3\times 5)^2$, and the total number of square factors is the same as the total number of divisors of $2^2\times3\times 5 $ (each being squared).